# How to transform a data frame to a row?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a very basic question about reshaping a table:

```
       pval     Quality
High  0.782        0.62
 Low  0.782        1.58
```

I would like to change it to

```
   pval     High     Low
  0.782     0.62    1.58
```

I am relatively new to R. Could someone help? Thanks!

Comment: `reshape` `melt` and drop duplicate then `t()`

Comment: `unlist(df)[-2]`

Comment: `t(unlist(df)[-2])` works. Thanks so much guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a straight `reshape()` if you bind the row names to the data first.

```
reshape(cbind(df, rn=rownames(df), row.names=NULL), 
    direction="wide", timevar="rn", idvar="pval")
#    pval Quality.High Quality.Low
# 1 0.782         0.62        1.58
```

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(pval = c(0.782, 0.782), Quality = c(0.62, 1.58
)), .Names = c("pval", "Quality"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("High", 
"Low"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `spread` in `tidyverse` package

```
 library(tidyverse)
 df1 %>% 
     rownames_to_column() %>% 
     spread(rowname, Quality)
```

Result

```
    pval High  Low
 1 0.782 0.62 1.58
```